# Как получить Class дженерика?

Tags: java, generics

Сложилась такая ситуация:

```
public class SomeChildObject extends SomeParentObject<List<SomeType>>
{
    public SomeChildObject()
    {
        //конструктор суперкласса требудет  
        //переменную типа Class<List<SomeType>> param
        super();
    }
}
```

Так вот, как получить `Class<List<SomeType>> param`?

Comment: [Третья ссылка в Гугле по запросу `java get generic type`][1]

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/66593/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471701/passing-a-class-with-type-parameter-as-type-parameter-for-generic-method-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В *Runtime* информация о конкретном выбранном типе недоступна, т.к. все *generics* после компиляции "стираются" и заменяются на *Object*.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что `SomeParentObject` определен так:

```
private static class SomeParentObject<T> {
  SomeParentObject(Class<T> t) {
    System.out.println(t.getClass());
  }
}
```

Во-первых, нужно понимать, что в runtime информация о типе в `Class<List<SomeType>>` стирается (английский термин `erasure`). Т.е. тип `t` в runtime это всегда просто `Class` и никакой информации о параметре `T` мы из объекта `t` получить не можем в принципе.

Однако, для случая описанного в вопросе используя reflection можно достать класс фактического аргумента generic-a:

```
class SomeChildObject extends SomeParentObject<List<SomeType>>
{
    public SomeChildObject()
    {
      super((Class<List<SomeType>>) (
            (ParameterizedType) (
                ((ParameterizedType) SomeChildObject.class.getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0])
            ).getRawType());
    }
}
```

Конечно, в данном конкретно случае делать этого особого смысла нет, так тут мы знаем тип аргумента generic-а статически и можем написать абсолютно эквивалентный код:

```
class SomeChildObject extends SomeParentObject<List<SomeType>>
{
    public SomeChildObject()
    {
      super((Class)List.class); // предупреждение компилятора можно безопасно
                                // игнорировать
    }
}
```

Но в некоторых ситуациях, т.е. когда тип `SomeChildObject` нам неизвестен статически, использование `Class.getGenericSuperclass` или `Class.getGenericInterfaces` чтобы достать фактические параметры обобщенных типов - это полезно. Пример:

```
class Specific {
    public Specific(String name) {
    }
}

class Factory<T> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T create(String name) throws Exception {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        Class<?> genericArgumentClass = (Class<?>)genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return (T) genericArgumentClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
    }
}


class SpecificFactory extends Factory<Specific> {}

...
Factory<Specific> factory = new SpecificFactory();
factory.create("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так получал:
//get(0) - определение типа первого дженерика

`val generic=(this.genericType as? ParameterizedType)?.actualTypeArguments?.get(0)`

В моём случае this это Field

Comment: Это не Java :)  Сюда не завезли Элвиса.